# Protractor - slow clicking on elements

Tags: protractor

Below is the code to click on radio button.

It clicks on radio button but the time it takes to click on next radio button is slow. Is there any way I can improve this?

```
   return element.all(by.css(selector)).filter((elem: any) => {
        return elem.getText().then((text: string) => {
            return text === data;
        });
    })
       .then((radio: any) => {
            browser.actions().mouseMove(radio[0]).perform()
                .then(() => {
                    radio[0].click();
                }).then(() => {
                Key.ENTER;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to perform the interaction in this way and are not using .click() directly on the radio[0] element?

Answer (score 0):

How about simplifying your code like that (as @DublinDev mentioned):

```
return $$(selector).filter((elem: ElementFinder) => {
    return elem.getText().then((text: string) => {
        return text === data;
    });
}).first().click();
```

Is `mouseMove` important in your case?

Moreover

```
.then(() => {
    Key.ENTER;
});
```

in your example actually does nothing.

Please tell me if it speeded up the test.